# Milo OPC UA Server push Values in Server Logic

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I'm a newbie to OPC UA.

My target is to create a OPC UA Server and as soon somebody changes any Value I want to receive a function call, so I can react on the Input.

To archive this, I created a server with MILO-Eclipse. In my Namespace I have some functions called onDataItemsModified() etc. But if I change a Value in my Server with UAExpert, the Server doesn't call the onDataItemsModified() Function. Is there another way to receive a notification as soon somebody changed a value on my Server? I saw the opportunity to add a client and register an observer, but I thought I can see the changes directly as Server and dosnt need to implement a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client writes to an attribute of a Node in your address space it comes in via the Write service, not any of the Monitored Item services.

You can override the write call in your address space, or simply add an AttributeObserver or an AttributeDelegate to the Nodes you create.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, thanks alot for your answer :) I tried to add an Observer. 
First I get my UaVariableNode. 
Then i add an ObserverClass which implements your AttributeObserver but the function "attributeChanged" is never called after I change a value in UaExpert. Do you know whats my mistake?

Comment: I changed the way to overwrite your call method. Now everything works fine! Thank you very much :) If some one want to see how it can be archived:  `@Override
     public void write(WriteContext arg0, List<WriteValue> arg1) {
      super.write(arg0, arg1);

      if(observer != null) {
       
       observer.checkValues(arg1);
      }
      
     }`